# multipart upload using resteasy 3.0.8 and spring boot 1.2.6

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resteasy

I'm getting the below exception, and I need a solution.

this is in the postman am submitting:

[image: g]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

errro trace:

```
17:51:18.223 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR c.x.i.e.InsightsExceptionMapper- Insights Datamanager server failure:   
javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: Could not find message body reader for type: interface org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile of content type: multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------338132133906954117275619
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerReaderInterceptorContext.throwReaderNotFound(ServerReaderInterceptorContext.java:52) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.getReader(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:73) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:50) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:59) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:53) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:150) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:89) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:112) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:296) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:250) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:237) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyHandlerAdapter.createModelAndView(ResteasyHandlerAdapter.java:96) [resteasy-spring-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyHandlerAdapter.handle(ResteasyHandlerAdapter.java:82) [resteasy-spring-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyHandlerAdapter.handle(ResteasyHandlerAdapter.java:26) [resteasy-spring-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyWebHandlerTemplate.handle(ResteasyWebHandlerTemplate.java:39) [resteasy-spring-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyHandlerAdapter.handle(ResteasyHandlerAdapter.java:47) [resteasy-spring-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:295) [spring-boot-actuator-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.xactly.logging.filter.MDCFilter.doFilter(MDCFilter.java:87) [commons-logging-logback-1.0.0-RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102) [spring-boot-actuator-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:69) [spring-boot-actuator-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_241]
17:51:18.239 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]- Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/insightsdmgr] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: com.xactly.insightsdmgr.beans.ResponseStatus of media type: application/octet-stream] with root cause  
org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: com.xactly.insightsdmgr.beans.ResponseStatus of media type: application/octet-stream
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:67) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:153) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyHandlerAdapter.createModelAndView(ResteasyHandlerAdapter.java:100) ~[resteasy-spring-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyHandlerAdapter.handle(ResteasyHandlerAdapter.java:82) ~[resteasy-spring-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyHandlerAdapter.handle(ResteasyHandlerAdapter.java:26) ~[resteasy-spring-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyWebHandlerTemplate.handle(ResteasyWebHandlerTemplate.java:39) ~[resteasy-spring-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.springmvc.ResteasyHandlerAdapter.handle(ResteasyHandlerAdapter.java:47) ~[resteasy-spring-3.0.8.Final.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:295) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.xactly.logging.filter.MDCFilter.doFilter(MDCFilter.java:87) ~[commons-logging-logback-1.0.0-RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:69) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_241]
```